# Vscode compile time error - Linking error?

Tags: c++

I have an issue when trying to compile my project. It gives me undefined errors. All the research online gives me suggestions that the compiler is not linking my files correctly. Here is my code and the errors associated with it.

MovieMonsterClass.h

```
#ifndef MonsterMainClass_h
#define MonsterMainClass_h

class MovieMonster
{
    protected:
    
    int Power = 0; // The level of power of the monster
    double Health = 0; // The number of health points 
    bool intellect = false; // Whether the monster is smart
    bool XtrSize = false; //Does the monster have superduper size?

    public:

    MovieMonster(int power = 0, double health = 0, bool intellect = false, bool xtrSize = false); // Constructor
    MovieMonster(); //Default Constructor
   
    ~MovieMonster(); // Destructor
    void setPower(int);// sets the power of the monster
    void setHealth(double);//sets the health of the monster
    void setXtrSize(bool); //sets whter the monster is Xtra in the size department
    void setIntellect(bool);//sets whter the monster is intelligent or a dummy!
    void print() const; // prints the monster values
};

#endif
```

MovieMonster.cpp

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <iomanip>
#include "MonsterMainClass.h"
  
using namespace std;

int p = 0;
double h = 0;
bool xtr = false;
bool smrt = false;

MovieMonster(p, h, xtr, smrt);

void MovieMonster::setPower(int p) // sets the power of the monster
{
    Power = p;
}

void MovieMonster::setHealth(double h) // set health function
{
    Health = h;
}

void MovieMonster::setXtrSize(bool xtr) // sets the size of monster Large or Small
{
    XtrSize = xtr;
}

void MovieMonster::setIntellect(bool smrt) // sets whether the monster is a dummy or sophisticated
{
    intellect = smrt;
}

void MovieMonster::print() const // prints the monsters characteristics
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        cout << "*";
    }
    cout << "Monster Power: " << Power << endl;
    cout << "Health: " << Health << endl;
    cout << "Xtr Size: " << XtrSize << endl;
    cout << "Intellect: " << intellect << endl;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        cout << "*";
    }  

}

MovieMonster::~MovieMonster() {}
```

CreateMonster.cpp

```
#include <iostream> 
#include "MonsterMainClass.h"
  
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    MovieMonster Renee;

    Renee.setHealth(.50);
    Renee.setIntellect(true);
    Renee.setXtrSize(true);
    Renee.setPower(100);
    Renee.print();

    return 0;
}
```

I am using a Windows machine and VS Code, as below:

```
Version: 1.60.2 (user setup)
Commit: 7f6ab5485bbc008386c4386d08766667e155244e
Date: 2021-09-22T12:00:31.514Z
Electron: 13.1.8
Chrome: 91.0.4472.164
Node.js: 14.16.0
V8: 9.1.269.39-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19043
```

What's strange is when I try and compile examples from the book I get the same errors. Any guidance is greatly appreciated!

Updated errors:

```
PS C:\Users\cdieckert-la\.vscode\COSC1436\Prog 2 Code test\Movie Monster Class> g++ .\CreateMonsters.cpp
.\CreateMonsters.cpp: In function 'int main()':
.\CreateMonsters.cpp:13:18: error: call of overloaded 'MovieMonster()' is ambiguous
     MovieMonster Monster;
                  ^~~~~~~
In file included from .\CreateMonsters.cpp:3:
.\MonsterMainClass.h:20:5: note: candidate: 'MovieMonster::MovieMonster()'
     MovieMonster(); //Default Constructor
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
.\MonsterMainClass.h:19:5: note: candidate: 'MovieMonster::MovieMonster(int, double, bool, bool)'
     MovieMonster(int power = 0, double health = 0, bool intellect = false, bool xtrSize = false); // Constructor
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: You are missing the implementation for the destructor. Add
`MovieMonster::~MovieMonster() {}`
to your MovieMonster.cpp

Btw. You shouldn't explicitly call the destructor, so `Renee.~MovieMonster();` is bad code.

Comment: The errors say that `MovieMonster::~MovieMonster()` is not defined. Can you point out where you think that it is defined? Because I am with your build tools....

Comment: also, please use proper code formatting, otherwise it's really hard to decipher the file structure

Comment: Note that explicitly calling the destructor in most cases is not only a bad idea, it typically leads to undefined behavior (because it will be called a second time automatically when the variable Renee goes out of scope). You definitely want to avoid undefined behavior at all costs!

Comment: Why is there a bunch of global variable is "MovieMonster.cpp"? Are you under the impression that you need to declare variables with the same names as the function arguments?

Comment: @Yunnosch - you are right, I did not have my deconstructor defined, I added it to the MovieMonster.cpp and that error cleared.

Comment: I am still getting this error now when I compile it with the deconstructor in the correct place.                                                                                                  :CreateMonsters.cpp:(.text+0x20a): undefined reference to `MovieMonster::MovieMonster(int, double, bool, bool)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @molbdnilo I thought I needed them? do I not need them?

Comment: I edited my original post to include your suggestions. I am now getting the error that the compiler is seeing two different constructors. The compiler won't compile it. Did I do it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The class definition (in `MonsterMainClass_h`) says that the class `MovieMonster` has a constructor that takes 4 arguments, a constructor that takes no arguments, and a destructor. None of those has a definition in the code posted in the question.

The code in `main` uses the four-argument constructor and the destructor. The error messages are pointing out that neither of those is defined anywhere.

So, as a first pass, add those definitions to `MovieMonster.cpp`.

And, as one comment notes, don't call `Renee.~MovieMonster();`. The compiler will do that at the end of `main`. That's the point of having a destructor: you don't have to worry about disposing of resources, because the destructor will be called implicitly.

And, don't `#include "MovieMonster.cpp"` in `CreateMonsters.cpp`. You have two source files that should be kept separate. Your project should name both files, so they can be compiled separately and linked.

And a note for the future: since all four arguments to the four-argument constructor have default values, it can be called with no arguments. So can the default constructor. The compiler will complain about code that uses no arguments (`MovieMonster monster;`), because both constructors could be used there.